# Is it okay to run Four #6 gage wires and Three #12 gage wires in 1" PVC Sced. 40?

Tags: wiring

Can I run a total of seven wires in a 1" Schedule 40 PVC conduit?

Four wires will be 6 gauge for a 50 amp hot tub.

Three wires will be 12 gauge for a 20 amp outdoor GFCI plug.

Comment: Use electrical rated PVC conduit

Comment: Are you sure you need to pull a full size neutral for the hot tub circuit? If it's only providing neutral to the hot tub disconnect's GFCI, then you only need to run 10AWG for it, and both circuits can share the same 10AWG ground for that matter

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- you addressed the shared ground, but not reducing the neutral

Comment: Aha! You're right. I missed that. And that's not something I'm 100% sure of. (I believe you, it is just not something as obvious as the reduced size ground.)

Comment: I've never actually done a fill calc. If you can physically pull it through 360 of bend it's prob fine. What no one seems to be mentioning is the de-rate after you have more than three current carrying conductors in conduit. "The same **conductor must be derated to 70% of its normal value when there are 7-9 current-carrying conductors** bundled together, and so on. The ampacity of conductors continues to decrease in Table 310.15(C)(1) as the number of conductors bundled together increases."

Comment: iirc *in free air*, 12g can do up to 30 amps. But bundled with more than three wires and in conduit, *then* you have to do math. It may be negligible (I haven't even looked at the table), or you may need to run 10g on a 20 amp CB, or protect your 12g with a 15 amp CB.

Comment: @Mazura There are at most **5** current carrying conductors here - 7 includes 2 grounds (which really only needs to be 1 ground, but irrelevant because grounds aren't current-carrying anyway).

Comment: @Mazura Actually, as I understand it (just confirmed with a bit of Googling) in a typical 120/240 circuit, the neutral doesn't count as a current carrying conductor because if both hots have (in this example) 50A, then the neutral gets 0A. And if one hot has 50A and the neutral has 50A it is because the other hot has 0A. etc. So effectively 2 out of 3. Which means effectively 4 conductors here, though "4-6" includes both 4 & 5, so it makes no practical difference.

Comment: My mind immediately goes to *de-rate* on a question like this. 'fill' *allows* you to put like nine 12g wires in a 1/2" EMT. *YOU* can't pull 9, 12g wires through more than two bends. - I'd cut four pieces of 6g and three 12g, and stick them into a 1" pipe. And then prob say, *boy this should be fun. Y'all got some lube?* (shared neutrals don't count, eh? And it doesn't matter, +1)

Answer (score 10):

You should be OK. Using the [Southwire calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit), 4 x 6 AWG = 24% + 3 x 12 AWG = 5% = 29% total.

Note that you only need one ground, and the size for grounds for circuits > 30A is generally smaller than the other conductors. So if my hunch is correct, you actually only need:

- 3 x 6 AWG (2 hot = black, red, etc.; 1 neutral = white or gray) = 18%
- 2 x 12 AWG (1 hot = black, red, etc.; 1 neutral = white or gray) = 4%
- 1 x 10 AWG (ground = bare or green) = 3%

For a total of < 24% fill (above numbers are all rounded up to nearest %).

As noted by others in answers & comments, you may actually be able to use 8 AWG for the 50A circuit hots and possibly even smaller for the 50A circuit neutral.

Comment: A better conduit fill calculator (there are several) will allow you to compute the whole set of different sized wires in one operation, rather than doing it piecemeal and adding it up yourself.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I know, but this wasn't that hard - only 3 sizes.

Comment: You may actually have to use *larger wire* (or smaller breakers) because of the de-rate(**?**).

Comment: @Mazura You may be right. But IIRC, the derate isn't that big a deal with only 2 circuits, and that generally the derate is from "maximum current possible" and other factors end up already keeping things lower (e.g., 12 AWG max. 20A everywhere even though it should be able to handle more, so derated it still ends up >= 20A). Assuming 6 AWG for 50A is copper, not aluminum, and assuming 75C rating, there is plenty of room for derating there too.

Comment: Number of *circuits* is meaningless. "current carrying conductors" ... which includes neutrals. Agree though, de-rate can be ignored as often as I ignore fill calcs.

Answer (score 4):

### You're making it bigger than it needs to be.

A 50A circuit using THHN wire in conduit can be run with 8 AWG copper wire, assuming terminals on both ends are listed for 75C thermal.

Further, a run to a hot tub *subpanel or disconnect* that ends some distance from the hot tub can be in significantly cheaper 6 AWG aluminum wire.  Subpanels have terminals rated for 75C and aluminum wire.  However, aluminum cannot get too close to a hot tub, as it does not play well with hot tub chemicals, nor do many insulation types such as UF, darned inconvenient, that!)

### Grounds too.

The ground only needs to be **10 AWG copper** (or 8 AWG aluminum if usable).

Grounds may be shared.  If "where the circuits split" is a good place for a splice (can't splice inside a conduit body*), you can use the same ground wire for both the hot tub and receptacle circuit.

Note that grounds must be green or bare, and neutrals must be natively white. You are not allowed to use tape to re-identify conductors at #6 or smaller.

---

* Well, to be very technical, if you splice inside a conduit body, you must follow the cubic-inch fill rules for junction boxes, not conduit bodies.  If you're choosing pipe sizes normally, then conduit bodies in that pipe size *are way too small* to work as junction boxes.